# Is there a better/faster way to query twitter for historic tweets containing a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

So I'm trying to get all tweets that match a certain search criteria since a certain year (At the moment I'm simply pulling X number of tweets and seeing if that number takes me back to the year I'm interested in).

The search criteria is simply a string contained within the tweet. So 'Apple' for example. I'm also trying to filter out RTs.

This is obviously going to be hundreds of thousands, probably more like millions of tweets.

To try and achieve this I have been using the Tweepy Twitter API:

```
def getTweets(searchValue, numOfTweets):

    i = 0  
    tweetStream = tweepy.Cursor(twitterAPI.search, q=searchValue, tweet_mode="extended").items(numOfTweets)
    f = open('csvfile.csv','w')
    while True:
        try:
            for tweet in tweetStream:
                if (tweet.full_text[0:2] != 'RT'):
                    print('Tweets processed:' + str(i))
                    f.write(str(formatTweet(tweet.full_text)))
                    f.write(str(tweet.created_at) + '\n')
                    i += 1
            #Break here when all tweets in the stream have been processed
            break
        except tweepy.TweepError:
            print('Sleeping for 2 mins to maintain Twitter API connection... \n')
            time.sleep(120)
    f.close()

return True
```

The problem is this runs incredibly slowly. Pulling maybe 50 tweets a second. If I need to go back several years this would mean leaving my program running for days/weeks.

I haven't used Tweepy before so I'm unsure of the best way to achieve what I want. My code is a mash up of several articles/answers I've seen elsewhere so I'm sure there are probably several issues with my method. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this documentation [developer.twitter.com](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/rate-limits)